# "Sort" VBA one sheet according to another (excel 2011)

Tags: excel, vba, macos, sorting, multiple-columns

I would like to sort one sheet ("sheet1") according to another ("sheet2") therefore moving cells accordingly to the cells movement in the other sheet.

Example:

```
Sheet1: A45 contains number: 3
sheet2: A45 contains number: 200
```

Sort (all) sheet2 (ascending, by columns) (it represent over a hundred columns)

```
sheet2 A45 (200) moves to A98
```

I would like it to make move:

```
sheet1 A45 (3) to A98
```

Today I am trying this, I know it works but only with PC excel 2003 (in French) and I cant figure why it does not work with mac excel 2011 (in english) :

```
Sub Test()
 
    Dim PlageFe1 As Range
    Dim PlageFe2 As Range
    Dim Tbl()
    Dim I As Long
 
    'plage en colonne A de la Feuille "Feuil1"
    With Worksheets("Feuil1")
 
        Set PlageFe1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
 
    End With
 
    'plage en colonne A de la Feuille "Feuil2"
    With Worksheets("Feuil2")
 
        Set PlageFe2 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
 
    End With
 
    'dimensionne le tableau par rapport à une des deux plages (ici la 1)
    ReDim Tbl(1 To 2, 1 To PlageFe1.Count)
 
    'fusionne les deux plages dans le tableau
    For I = 1 To UBound(Tbl, 2)
 
        Tbl(1, I) = PlageFe1(I)
        Tbl(2, I) = PlageFe2(I)
 
    Next I
 
    'effectue le tri (adapter le signe < ou > dans la porc "Tri")
    Tri Tbl()
 
    'puis réaffecte les valeurs
    For I = 1 To UBound(Tbl, 2)
 
        PlageFe1(I) = Tbl(1, I)
        PlageFe2(I) = Tbl(2, I)
 
    Next I
 
End Sub
 
Sub Tri(Tbl())
 
    Dim Tempo1, Tempo2
 
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
            'éffectue un tri décroissant "<"
            'pour un tri croissant ">"
    For I = 1 To UBound(Tbl, 2) - 1
 
        For J = I + 1 To UBound(Tbl, 2)
 
            'tri sur l'index 1
            If Tbl(1, I) > Tbl(1, J) Then
 
                Tempo1 = Tbl(1, J)
                Tempo2 = Tbl(2, J)
                Tbl(1, J) = Tbl(1, I)
                Tbl(2, J) = Tbl(2, I)
                Tbl(1, I) = Tempo1
                Tbl(2, I) = Tempo2
 
            End If
 
    Next J, I
 
End Sub
```

Comment: How are the two sheets correlated?  Is there a column or columns in both sheets that have the same unique values? Or are they just related by position as it is now?

Comment: This site is not intended for requests of entire code projects; it is for specific questions. Have you attempted this already and failed at a specific point? Where did you succeed/fail?

Comment: Both sheets have no relations what so ever excepted locations. I am sorry but i am new to VBA and I am struggling and searching the web since 3 weeks now. I have made several atemps since then (using mainly indirect...

Comment: but nothing really succesfull, I don't even know if it is possible with excel??

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this:

```
Sub SpecialSort()

Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range

' Current Selection
Set Rng1 = Selection
' Equivalent Selection on sheet 1
Set Rng2 = Sheets(1).Range(Rng1.Address)

' Cut the part from the first sheet
Rng2.Cut
' Insert it before the range to be sorted
Rng1.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
' Keep track of this new inserted part
Set Rng3 = Rng1.Parent.Range(Rng2.Address)
' Sort by the column in question
With Rng1.Parent.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Rng1, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Union(Rng1, Rng3): .Header = xlNo: .MatchCase = False: .Orientation = xlTopToBottom: .SortMethod = xlPinYin: .Apply
End With
' Cut the sorted part
Rng3.Cut
' Put it back
Rng2.Parent.Select: Rng2.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
' Delete the section you cut
Rng3.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Set Rng1 = Nothing: Set Rng2 = Nothing: Set Rng3 = Nothing

End Sub
```

It works by selecting a range (including a whole column), it finds the equivalent range on the first sheet, and orders that second range according to the way the selection is sorted (using the first column as a key).

Even if this is not exactly what you need, perhaps you could modify it accordingly.

Comment: Yes I have attempted similar ways: inserting one every two row in the same sheet then sorting then using indirect to copy the sorted data into a new sheet but then my problem is: how can I sort every two columns with a range ONLY including the curent and the last column

Comment: and having that as a VBA to repeat every two rows on too multiple rows (over a hundred).

Comment: I'm sorry I was not able to help.  I guess I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you are trying to do and how it differs from my solution.  I wish you good luck and hope that someone else will be able to better assist.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!, it is geting there, maybe I am not clear enough but the things is: i need to do exatly what you sayd but on to each columns independently from one an other